# How to use Views Rules?

Tags: views, rules

I've looked here: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules but can't get past 2.2 *Add a "Rules" display*.

I don't know what that means. I've installed Views Rules but can't find any Rules option anywhere in my Views.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: thanks for mentioning the [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) module. I didn't know it, but I'm sure it will be handy in the future.

It seems that you're not quite familiar with the Views module. While creating or editing your View, you should click the "add" button at the top, right underneath "Displays". When you select "Rules", a new display is added and there appears a little button with the text "Rules" in it. (I've already added one in the picture underneath.)

[image: Rules display]

Afterwards, configure the Rules' settings by clicking "edit the field info" and choose the desired data types.

[image: Rules settings]

Finally, select the View you would like to use in your Rule. In my case, the View is called "Test".

[image: Choose View]

Comment: Now I found the Display and Rules but now I get 2 Views in 1. I opened an already existing View and then Add Rules and it opened up a new View. Does this mean I have to make it Rules View from start?

Comment: @disallgbg: That's perfectly normal. The purpose of the displays is exactly that you can use the same view at different places with different settings. Therefore, you can simply add a Rules display to your existing view and you're done.